# WPF: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlnode

I'm accessing this method using WPF. I know that when accessing objects from an outside method, I should use a Dispatcher. Or the "node" is a local variable and it is giving me:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why?

Here's the Code:

```
SpeechSynthesizer valery = new SpeechSynthesizer();
XmlDocument xmlNews = new XmlDocument();
xmlNews.Load(string.Format("http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=tc&output=rss"));
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNews.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item"))
{
    valery.Speak(node.SelectSingleNode("/title").InnerXml);
}
```

Comment: Is `xmlNews` assigned to anything? The same goes for `valery`

Comment: XmlDocument xmlNews = new XmlDocument();
SpeechSynthesizer valery = new SpeechSynthesizer();

Comment: `valery` could be null, `xmlNews` could be null and the result of `node.SelectSingleNode` could be null. If I'm being honest I suspect the last one, which means the attempted call to `InnerXml` is triggering the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm being honest I suspect `node.SelectSingleNode` is returning null, which means the attempted call to `InnerXml` is triggering the exception.

Try making the following changes:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNews.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item"))
{
    var titleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/title");

    if (titleNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleNode.InnerXml))
        valery.Speak(titleNode.InnerXml);
}
```

I put the check on `InnerXml` as well just in case `Speak` cannot take null strings.

I don't initially suspect the XPath because those methods will return empty collections instead of null items if the XPath doesn't find anything.

Comment: You were right! node.SelectSingleNode is returning null i changed the code to foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNews.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/title")) and it works like I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take out your forward slash and try again. See below:

```
SpeechSynthesizer valery = new SpeechSynthesizer();
XmlDocument xmlNews = new XmlDocument();
xmlNews.Load(string.Format("http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=tc&output=rss"));
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNews.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item"))
{
    valery.Speak(node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerXml);
}
```

This worked for me